# IOU application with email integration

Tags: webapp-rec

Currently I track how much money I owe people by emailing myself. Is there a web application for simplifying this with decent email support - ie. I can email it who I owe, how much and what for and which will let me know if it couldn't understand the email?

Comment: since you keep forgetting, you still owe me $1750.88 ;-)

Comment: Related: [Web App for managing shared bills](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/web-app-for-managing-shared-bills)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Billmonk](https://www.billmonk.com/) definitely. It sends emails whenever a new bill is shared among users, you can shuffle debts when many people owe money to others in the same group. It supports receiving instructions via [SMS emails](https://www.billmonk.com/about/sms) (SMS sent to an email address), but I'm not sure if a regular email would work though.

**Update:** Billmonk regularly fails to work correctly (repeating bills haven't worked for months now) and I wouldn't recommend people to use it anymore until everything is fixed.

Comment: I tried contacting support, don't have any info back yet as to whether regular emails work

Comment: Actually, it does appear to handle email. Just a bit slow sometimes

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like [Evernote](http://evernote.com) and just email it the text you want. It won't parse it for you or store it in special fields... but if use a convention such as "John owes me $5 for lunch", you could easily enter a search term like `intitle:"John owes"` to find all those notes. They also give you an @evernote.com email address which allows you to create notes via email.

Comment: That could work (I do have an Evernote account), but I was curious as to whether there were any special tools

Answer (score 0):

- [BillMonk](https://www.billmonk.com/)
- <strike>[Billshare](http://billshare.org/)</strike>
- [Buxfer](http://buxfer.com/)
- [billster](http://www.billster.net/)
- [Texthog](https://www.texthog.com)

Comment: Billshare says that it is going to close soon

Comment: I looked through the sites, but I couldn't find any way of submitting bills via email.

Comment: added Texthog, which may do what you are looking for