# Web app for managing shared bills?

Tags: webapp-rec

When I was a student, like most students, I used to share a house with 4 others. We had lots of bills, each in a different person's name. It would have been good if there was a good web app for tracking who paid what and who owed whom what.

Does anyone know of such a webapp?

Answer (score 2):

I have used [BillMonk](https://www.billmonk.com/) for this in the past and found it very useful.

Comment: I have used Billmonk for the last few years, but lately it has become so unstable I would recommend looking for an alternative. In its better years it was truly awesome, but now it's not worth the time. The closest alternative I could find was SplitMyBill.

Answer (score 0):

[BillQ](http://www.mybillq.com/) is another good service that has a free account.

Answer (score 0):

[WePay.com](http://wepay.com) does group payment

Answer (score 0):

My website [WeLoveBills.com](http://welovebills.com) does exactly what you want. It gives students a space to organise their house bills so that each user will always be able to see who has and who hasn't paid each bill.Please check it out. :)

Regards

Joe

Answer (score 0):

[SplitMyBill.ie](http://www.splitmybill.ie/history) is another alternative. It has limited functionality but it covers the basics well.

Answer (score 0):

In 2006 I wrote [Billster](http://www.billster.net/) to solve this exact problem. I'm trying to justify spending some more time upgrading the system, but it's still stable and free.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the webapps mentioned by others. 
I recommend [shortreckonings.com](http://shortreckonings.com) : good UX , unlimited users.