# To manage shared household expenses: Billshare or Bills Are In?

Tags: webapp-rec

I saw [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/web-app-for-managing-shared-bills) question, which was not definitively answered. I also found [Billshare](http://billshare.org/) and [Bills Are In](https://www.billsarein.com/) through Lifehacker a few months back, and those look to be 2 of the more promising sites.

So I was wondering if anyone has had experience with one or both of these sites? How do they compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Billshare website:

> Please Note: Adding new receipts and payments has been disabled. Please save a copy of your data as billshare will close soon.

I tried to check the blog, but it does not seem to be up and running. Not to be a smartass or anything, but I think that the biggest difference is that Bills Are In still seems to be functional.

Comment: haha oops I guess I missed that one and now I have my answer. Thanks.